# locks/condition variables issue

Tags: concurrency, locks

So in the program I'm writing I have three functions, let's call them A, B and C for simplicities sake. Each function needs to access resource X to work.

The restrictions are that A and B are not allowed to run concurrently and must be synchronized appropriately. C is allowed however to run concurrently with either A or B.

This is causing me some issues.

First I tried putting locks on A and B so when A is called it acquires the lock to X and then releases it and same as B. This way A and B run sequentially. However if I use locks in this manner C is unable to run concurrently with A or B.

So I tried using condition variables where A had to wait for a signal from B if B was running and B had to wait for a signal from A, but this sort of interdependent calling didn't seem to work either.

Don't know what to do.

Comment: If (**and only if**) access from C to the resource doesn't need to be serialized then you do not need to put any lock on C BUT this is a pretty strange situation (to run concurrently doesn't mean that they can access a shared resource in the same moment). Please post more details about what you want to do and what OS/language you're using

Comment: I'm writing my code in C on my mac. So the shared resource here is a branch of a bank, functions A and B are withdrawal and deposit respectively, and C is transfer. I am not supposed to be able to concurrently do a withdrawal and deposit from the same branch (even on different accounts in the branch) but I can do transfers concurrently within the branch as long as the accounts doing the transferring are not the same as the ones handling a deposit/withdrawal. This has to do with keeping the total branch balance from being corrupted.

Comment: So just do not put any lock for transferring (but you'll have to lock somehow at a lower level for account). How to implement this depends on what you're using (is this an example and you access a database directly? you talk with some kind of service?). Personally I wouldn't use a double lock so I would use a account-level locking (for A, B and C) expanding to _any account_ for A and B. Because these operations comes from human users you may think to use a mechanism like the _optimistic lock_ commonly used in DB for A/B vs C and a simple sw lock for A and B.

Comment: So what you're saying is to only set locks at the account level and not at the branch level? I'm not sure what you mean by "expanding to any account for A and B"

Comment: I mean: put a software lock (_critical section_) to serialize A and B and let C free to work. Because you need an account-level synchronization I would use a mechanism like _optimistic lock_ (at database or service level) to synchronize A/B with C (and to grant another level of security for A/B too).

Answer (score 0):

Without having control over the language, only talking about theory, it seems there is a simple way. If X is persistent, and A, B, and C can be called in a way which touches X, then A, B, and C ought to pass in their name in when accessing X, say, through a method called D. Here would be what D does:

- Take in caller name, and arguments.
- If caller is C, pass the arguments to X.
- If caller is A or B, check if there is a lock on X.
- If there is no lock, send the arguments to X.
- If there is a lock, wait for an opening.

So basically wrap X with D. You could even simplify further and have D take in a locking or non-locking argument instead of a name. If locking, check lock and possibly wait, if not locking, pass arguments.

This approach might seem overly simple, but I don't know a lot of your actual situation. I see the question was asked a while ago also, so I don't know if you need help any longer.